# How to add a table in flutter quill?

Tags: android, flutter, quill

Is there any way to add a table in flutter_quill with n columns and m rows that the user can give?

I'm now building an app that is using the editor [flutter_quill] (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill) and I have already added all buttons I want except (add table).

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar feature in my app. Where we needed to insert and edit table in textfield. I used [quill_html_editor](https://pub.dev/packages/quill_html_editor) for it.

It has all features of flutter_quill along with table options.